nginx proxy pass to nodejs running on same server at port 3000
I have a requirement where i proxy pass the request coming on my server ip to nodejs server which is running on the same server at port 3000 so that when i access my application using browser i don't have to give ip:port on the browser but instead i just hit on the browser ip and then nginx proxy pass the request to nodejs which is running on port 3000
I tried to write this code but it did not work when i try to access application by ip:3000 it works but my requirement is to access it using just ip not with port
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name 44.195.67.159;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

